# iphone navigation push problems

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I use two buttons in UIViewController and the UIViewcontroller is included navigationcontroller.

And I use below code, want to load tableview.

```
-(IBAction)page2Pressed
{

 page2View *page2 = [[page2View alloc] initWithNibName:@"page2View" bundle:nil];

 page2.title = @"page2";

 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:page2 animated:YES];

 [page2 release];
}

-(IBAction)page3Pressed
{ 
 page2View *page3 = [[page2View alloc] initWithNibName:@"page2View" bundle:nil];

 page3.title = @"page3";

 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:page3 animated:YES];

 [page3 release];
}
```

in the page2pressed action, the Navigationcontroller can load page2view (tableview), 
but page3pressed action, navigationcontroller can't load page2view correctly.

when page3pressed done, the application load page2 and page3,

So, in page3pressed action, push event is occurred twice.. home -> page2 -> page3..

Can I solve this problem? I want to use one "page2View" respectively..

please give some answer

Comment: You are doing same thing in both IBAction methods, so instead use only one IBAction method.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I want to use two IBAction and each IBAction should load same "page2View". I want to use one nib or class for several times use.. I'm sorry my english.. hmm..

Comment: Hi, Once Check, which method is calling, when you pressed page3 button.

Comment: You are showing same page with only different title or any thing else you need.

Answer (score 0):

check in interface builder if your button is not attached with the two action methods i.e. page3Pressed, and also page2Pressed

Comment: it looks that when pressing button both action methods being called